# Strange log4j declaration

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I have a problem with an old project: The log file doesn't append in the console view of Eclipse. Instead of declaring the properties of log4j uses in log4j.xml or log4j.properties, the logger is defined in java:

```
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;


public class GCLogger {
    private static GCLogger _self;
    private Logger logger;

    private static final String NAME_FILE = "fichierLog.log";

    public static GCLogger getInstance() {
        if (_self == null || _self.logger == null) {
            GCLogger logger = new GCLogger();
            logger.initLogger();
            _self = logger;
        }
        return _self;
    }

    public void error(String msg, Exception e) {
        if (logger != null) {
            logger.error(msg, e);
        }
    }

    public void debug(String msg) {
        if (logger != null) {
            logger.debug(msg);
        }
    }

    private void initLogger() {
        logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
        PatternLayout monLayout = new PatternLayout("%d{DATE} - %5p %c{1} - %m%n");
        logger.removeAllAppenders();

        try {
            File repLogs = new File(GCConstants.GC_REPERTOIRE_LOGS);
            if (!repLogs.exists()) {
                repLogs.mkdir();
            }

            fa = new FileAppender(monLayout, GCConstants.GC_REPERTOIRE_LOGS + File.separator + NAME_FILE, true);
            fa.activateOptions();
            fa.setImmediateFlush(true);

            logger.addAppender(fa);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to show `fichierLog.log` in the console view (using eclipse configuration)?

If not, what is the minimal change to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum change - add a console appender:

```
ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(monLayout); // re-use the layout
logger.addAppender(console);
```

<opinion>
However, if you're making other changes to the codebase, I would strongly recommend changing this to use external configuration - it'll make your life much easier in the long (and probably short) term.</opinion>